# C# Server receive successful only when socket is closed

Tags: c#, sockets

Android：

```
btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        strMessage = textSend.getText().toString();
        new Thread(sendThread).start();
        }
});

Runnable sendThread = new Runnable() {      
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        byte[] sendBuffer = null;
        try {
            sendBuffer = strMessage.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            outStream.write(sendBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

C#：

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] content = reader.ReadBytes(20);
    string receivemessage = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(content);
    // string receivemessage = reader.ReadString();
    lbMessageView.Invoke(showMessageCallback, receivemessage);
    Thread acceptThread = new Thread(acceptClientConnect);
    acceptThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: This is a very low quality post, I'm afraid. Seeing your code is meaningless unless you can explain to other users what it does. Also helpful would be to know what you want it to do and exactly what the problem is. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to improve quality.

Comment: Sorry，I did did not do it regularly,but I will do it well next time

Answer (score 1):

i think you need flush stream on client side. If you do not call flush() method, socket will fire when it is closed.

```
try {
           outStream.write(sendBuffer);
           outStream.flush();

     } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```